# Access sub interface values in the same function

Tags: python

I had two classes - main and sub interface

There is a pushbutton which will calls out the sub interface and I am trying to get the output of the sub tool interface directly (or almost immediately) so that it can be use within the push button function.

In my code, if I did the following:

- hit on 'Click Me'
- checked 2 options and hit the 'Apply to selected item' in the sub interface
- the print line of 'my dict values' is still empty

Unless I create another function `get_results` in which then `self.my_dict` will be shown correctly.

As such, how can I code it in a way that once the 'Apply...' button is hit, `self.my_dict` will be updated without the need of creating another function? Or am I just overthinking things?

```
class SubMenuWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, menu_items, parent=None):
        super(SubMenuWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.my_lyt = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.checked_options = []
        self.sel = {}

        for menu_name, submenu_name in menu_items.items():
            # Set the main menu item name
            self.groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self)
            self.groupbox.setTitle(menu_name)
            self.groupbox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
            self.my_lyt.addWidget(self.groupbox)

            if submenu_name:
                sub_txt = [action for action in submenu_name]
                for s in sub_txt:
                    sub_chk = QtGui.QCheckBox(s)
                    self.checked_options.append(sub_chk)
                    self.groupbox.layout().addWidget(sub_chk)

        apply_tag_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Apply to selected item')
        apply_tag_btn.clicked.connect(self.get_checked_options)

        self.my_lyt.addWidget(apply_tag_btn)
        self.my_lyt.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(self.my_lyt)
        self.show()

    def get_checked_options(self):
        for f in self.checked_options:
            if f.isChecked():
                self.sel[f.parent().title()] = f.text()

class MainWin(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__(parent)

        self.my_dict = {}

        btnA = QtGui.QPushButton('Click Me')
        btnA.clicked.connect(self.get_options)

        btnB = QtGui.QPushButton('Get results')
        btnB.clicked.connect(self.get_results)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(btnA)
        layout.addWidget(btnB)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def get_options(self):
        sample_dict = {'GrpA' : ['John', 'Zack'], 'GrpB' : ['Alice', 'Phan']}
        self.subWin = SubMenuWindow(sample_dict)

        # I had want to get the values from subWin as soon as User has hit on
        # the 'Apply to selected item' button
        self.my_dict = self.subWin.sel
        print ">>> my dict values : ", self.my_dict
        # do something else from here thereafter...

    def get_results(self):
        print self.subWin.sel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the new window will not block, so your print statements will be executed before the user has anything selected. You could pass in a callback to notify the calling widget when the user changes the selection.

for example:

```
class SubMenuWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, menu_items, parent=None, callback=None):
        super(SubMenuWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.callback = callback
        [...]

    def get_checked_options(self):
        for f in self.checked_options:
            if f.isChecked():
                self.sel[f.parent().title()] = f.text()
        if self.callback:
            self.callback()
```

and pass in the callback:

```
    def get_options(self):
        sample_dict = {'GrpA' : ['John', 'Zack'], 'GrpB' : ['Alice', 'Phan']}
        self.subWin = SubMenuWindow(sample_dict, callback=self.get_results)
        [...]
```

this way your `get_result` method will be called whenever the user clicks the apply button in the `SubMenuWindow`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for my cause. About the callback that you have implemented, is that a default signal in QWidget? I could not find much info while looking through the QWidget doc page...